# Crash issue in ad-hoc build while drawing

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm facing a crash issue in following code (only in Ad-Hoc build).

```
- (void)drawPreviewInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGColorRef strokeColor = [self.delegate.strokeColor CGColor];
    CGFloat strokeWidth = self.delegate.strokeWidth;

    CGFloat x = rect.size.width/2.0f;
    CGFloat y = rect.size.height/2.0f;
    CGPoint strokePoint = CGPointMake(x, y);

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, strokePoint.x, strokePoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, strokePoint.x, strokePoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

The crash log shows the following picture:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x10000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39f535b0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreGraphics                    0x3237c3ec CGColorRetain + 12
2   CoreGraphics                    0x3237c592 CGGStateSetStrokeColor + 38
```

The code works perfectly fine in development environment (on both simulator and device). Any theories? I'm working under ARC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with object retain and release -- which was being handled by ARC. Apparently, ARC still has some issues, specifically with UIColor -> CGColor. The problem is explained here: http://blog.bignerdranch.com/296-arc-gotcha-unexpectedly-short-lifetimes/

I changed the following lines to code:

```
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeWidth);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor);
```

to this, and it's working now:

```
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.delegate.strokeWidth);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.delegate.strokeColor.CGColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick guess: `self.delegate` isn't set to `nil` in your `init` which causes `CGColor` to be called on a random bit of memory.

---

In more detail: During development builds object variables tend to all be set to nice friendly `nil` values. When you make a release build this isn't the case. A crash like this is most likely to be something not being initialised to `nil`.

It could be almost anywhere though; because an object variable 'somewhere' is pointing to a random bit of memory.

You can try the Analyse tool in Xcode to see if it picks up on anything. Beyond that you'll have to work backwards from the object where it's crashing up through it's parents and check everything is initialised nicely.